# gui/tool to manage full-text in SQL Server 2008 express

Tags: sql-server-2008

so apparently SQL Server 2008 express doesn't let you graphically manage full-text and such. I was wondering if there is a tool/addon to do that.

I came across this :
http://fulltextmanager.codeplex.com/

However, I'm having a hard time getting it to work. It's complaining about path being null or something. (I was reading up on Full-Text in sql 2008, and it shouldn't even be using path column at first place, so I don't what's going on. If any of you have used this with 2008 express, then let me know how it went with you.)

Any other tools?

Comment: Is SQL Server 2008 Express all that you have?  When I run my full version Management Studio against Express I get the storage node, properties, and a gui for building the catalog: http://screencast.com/t/csA5Y5TEvh

Comment: that's all I got

Answer (score 0):

Have you grabbed the free [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en)? I couldn't really tell from your post but it certainly offers quite a few GUI means to accomplish tasks.

Comment: I do have Management Studio, but it doesn't have GUI to manage full-text like non-express versions do.